# Liveliness QoS setting for service server and service client

Tags: ros2

I need help with the following:

What does the liveliness QoS mean for service action and service client in ROS2?
What can be compatible liveliness settings between the two?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following documents may help: [Quality of Service settings](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html), and [ROS QoS - Deadline, Liveliness, and Lifespan](https://design.ros2.org/articles/qos_deadline_liveliness_lifespan.html)